# Typescript, Importing a svg file returns a string but importing a less file returns an empty object

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a less file; I have a svg. Uh typescript.

```
.red {
  color: #1330af;
} .blue {
  color: red;
}
```

I have a custom.d.ts and I have two imports

```
declare module '*.svg';
declare module '*.less'
//custom.d.ts

import * as logo from './logo.svg'
import * as style from './style.less'
//Some ts file
```

Can someone explain why the logo is a string, but style is an object that is empty?
Is there any way of loading the css to the style variable? Other than using tools like `typings-for-css-modules-loader`

Comment: Typescript only support importing js / ts modules, not able to load any other resources. This kind of import should be configured by your build / bundler like webpack or else with proper loader configuration. If you are using bare typescript only, there's no way to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

> an someone explain why the logo is a string, but style is an object that is empty?

It depends on how the loaders work in `webpack`.

- The svg loader returns a string
- The less loader is probably adding the generated .css to a `style` tag.